# Impossible to connect Google Data Studio to AWS RDS Aurora mysql with ssl mandatory

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-aurora

My Aurora mysql cluster is setup with SSL and TLS 1.2 mandatory
I white-listed the Google IPs in my security group

On my client side, I generated a client certificate with the following command:

```
 openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout client.key -x509 -days 365 -out client.crt
```

On my client side I downloaded the CA certificate from RDS here: https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/us-east-1/us-east-1-bundle.pem

[This is my ssl configuration in Googlee Data Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnoyz.png)

[This is the error message when I click on authenticate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAtMY.png)

Could you help me to understand what is the issue?